# How to use ScrapySharp to parse elements in an html document?

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping, html-agility-pack, scrapysharp

Here's the project official "Documentation":

https://bitbucket.org/rflechner/scrapysharp/wiki/Home

---

No matter what I try, I can't find the `CssSelect()` method that the library is supposed to add to make querying things easier. Here's what I've tried:

```
using ScrapySharp.Core;
using ScrapySharp.Html.Parsing;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.stackoverflow.com");

var page = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
page.CssSel???
```

Exactly how do I use this library? In the documentation it isn't clear what type `html` is.

Comment: I have just updated Wiki of the project. https://bitbucket.org/rflechner/scrapysharp/wiki/Home I hope it will be easier to use. Bye

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add

```
using ScrapySharp.Extensions;
```

It looks like you're missing that.  That should make `CssSelect` available.

Just in case an example helps, here's a method, as well, that I use in a project:

```
private string GetPdfUrl(HtmlDocument document, string baseUrl)
{
    return new Uri(new Uri(baseUrl), document.DocumentNode.CssSelect(".table-of-content .head-row td.download a.text-pdf").Single().Attributes["href"].Value).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Almost 10 years later and the repository's readme examples still don't include this.